# Adding Date and Integer in jQuery

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function duedatecal(){
 var dmy = $(".invoicedate").val().split("/");     
  alert(dmy);  // it is in the format of mm/dd/yyyy 
var invoicedate = new Date(
               parseInt(dmy[2], 10),
               parseInt(dmy[1], 10) - 1,
               parseInt(dmy[0], 10)
             );
alert(invoicedate.getDate()); //Getting the month Value but need to get the date value
var paymentterms = $(".paymentterms").text();
 alert(paymentterms);
var dueDate = new Date();
dueDate.setDate(invoicedate.getDate()+parseInt(paymentterms)); //need to add paymentterms to date but here adding to the month
alert(dueDate);
$(".duedate").html(dueDate);  //not getting the output displayed

}
</script>
     <apex:form>
        Date:
         <Apex:inputtext value="{!dateIn}" id="time" styleclass="invoicedate" onblur="duedatecal();"/> //say suppose date is 06/03/2013
        Payment Days:
           <apex:outputtext value="{!payment.Net__c}" styleclass="paymentterms"  /> //say suppose will get 10 days here
        Due date:
           <apex:outputtext value="{!duedate}" styleclass="duedate"/> // output shld be 16/03/2013
        </apex:form>
```

Here the {!duedate} is not getting displayed in the outputtext(Added all the errors I'm facing in javascript code).Where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. I've just formatted the date to the 'MM/DD/YYYY', used `jQuery` syntax instead of '$' and some of javascript date functions like `parse`:

```
function duedatecal(){
    var invoicedate = new Date(Date.parse(jQuery(".invoicedate").val()));
    invoicedate.setDate(invoicedate.getDate() + parseInt(jQuery(".paymentterms").text()));
    jQuery(".duedate").html((invoicedate.getMonth()+1) + '/' +invoicedate.getDate() + '/' + invoicedate.getFullYear());  
}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: edited my code.Can u check it once

Comment: @EagerinSf I've updated my example

Comment: here 06/03/2013 is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.I need to add payment days to date but not to month like `06/03/2013 + 10 = 06/13/2013` help Pls

Comment: @EagerinSf Ok, updated the code again. Try it and if it is ok then rate my answer.